# How to make my code accept only numbers (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x

(Scroll down for changes)

I know many have probably already asked this, but i have looked at a few solutions to other people's questions and whatever i have tried has not worked.
I am very new to coding and i have to code a calculator for school. I have the following code which accepts input for numbers from the user:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))
```

When i enter a letter however, I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 40, in 
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'd'

Can someone help me to be able to make it so that it only accepts numbers? Here is the rest of my code:

```
import time 

def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

def power(x, y):
    return x ** y

print("Welcome to the Calculator App!\n")
print("Select operation.\n")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")
print("5.To the Power of\n")

choice = input("Enter choice(1, 2, 3, 4 or 5):")

while choice not in ("1","2","3","4","5"):
    print("Invalid Input")
    choice = input("Enter choice(1, 2, 3, 4 or 5):")

num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))    

while choice == '5' and num1 >= 1000000000:
    print("\nFirst number too high\n")
    num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

while choice == '5' and num2 >= 30:
    print("\nSecond number too high")
    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

while choice == '4' and num2 == 0:
    print("\nCannot divide by zero")
    num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

if choice == '1':
    print(" ")
    print(num1,"+",num2,"=", add(num1,num2))

elif choice == '2':
    print(" ")
    print(num1,"-",num2,"=", subtract(num1,num2))

elif choice == '3':
    print(" ")
    print(num1,"*",num2,"=", multiply(num1,num2))

elif choice == '4':
    print(" ")
    print(num1,"/",num2,"=", divide(num1,num2))

elif choice == '5':
    print(" ")
    print(num1,"**",num2,"=", power(num1,num2))

else:
    print("\nInvalid input")

time.sleep(10)
```

This is my code for that section now:

```
num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
while True:
    try:
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Please enter only a number")
        continue
    else:
    break
```

When i run that and deliberately enter the letter g, I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "python", line 32 in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'g'
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `)` on the previous line...

Comment: Thanks, i didn't see that. I ran it after fixing that, and it is still have issues (hence my edit)

Comment: Read through the answer in the linked duplicate - it solves the issue you describe...